React Native rounded button icon not centering
I am trying to create a button with a plus icon centered in the middle however if I use react-native-vector-icons then it has extra spacing underneath and if I use <Text>+</Text> it has extra spacing above. I have tried the solutions from React Native: Perfectly align Text in circle but nothing has worked yet.
Button code:
<View>
  <Pressable
    style={styles.button}
    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Add Habit')}>
    <Icon name="plus" size={40} color={'black'} />
  </Pressable>
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#219ebc',
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 100,
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 3,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10,
    lineHeight: 0,
  },
});




Can you add a screenshot showing the UI?

There is a little misalignment because the icon used has a different size. You can use other icons like FontAwesome5, FontAwesome6, or others from the library. If you use the same icon, you can force the icon alignment by transform with translateY, it's valid for the text too.

import { FontAwesome, FontAwesome5, FontAwesome6 } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert('The button was pressed!')}
      >
        <FontAwesome style={styles.iconBg}  name="plus" size={40} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert('The button was pressed!')}
      >
        <FontAwesome style={[styles.iconBg, styles.iconCentered]}  name="plus" size={40} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert('The button was pressed!')}
      >
        <FontAwesome5 style={styles.iconBg}  name="plus" size={40} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert('The button was pressed!')}
      >
        <FontAwesome6 style={styles.iconBg}  name="plus" size={40} color="black" />
      </Pressable>
      <Pressable
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => alert('The button was pressed!')}
      >
        <Text style={[styles.iconBg, styles.text]}>+</Text>
      </Pressable>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  iconBg: {
    // Comment the next line to remove the bgColor
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  iconCentered: {
    transform: [
      {
        translateY: 1.5
      }
    ]
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 40,
    lineHeight: 40,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#219ebc',
    width: 75,
    height: 75,
    borderRadius: 75,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    elevation: 3,
  },
});

You can see the full example on this Expo Snack.

I used @expo/vector-icons because it uses react-native-vector-icons.


Amazing! Thank you for the in-depth explanation, it's been so frustrating looking at the icon just slightly off centre
